# Get Complete User List in Microsoft Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

im using EWS on a Exchange 2010 SP2 server

i cant seem to find any command/documentation for retrieving a complete list of all users (mailboxes/aliases) in the exchange server

the question has been asked several times but i havent seen any answer

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2010 with EWS there is no operation that will return this you only have the ResolveName operation and the expandgroup operation. So in EWS you can use a workaround of putting all the users you want to be returned in a group and then using ExpandGroup on that Group.

Otherwise you should use either LDAP directly using System.DirectoryServices eg http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/10/25/Searching-the-Global-Address-List-C-Edition.aspx or use the Exchange Management Shell and Get-Mailbox see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159(v=exchg.150).aspx

One other workaround is if you have less the 100 objects in your GAL you can use "SMTP:" with resolveName eg

```
        PropertySet cntProp = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        NameResolutionCollection ncCol = service.ResolveName("SMTP:", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, cntProp);
        foreach (NameResolution nc in ncCol) { 
            if(nc.Contact.Alias != null){
                Console.WriteLine("Address : " + nc.Mailbox.Address);
                Console.WriteLine("Alias : " + nc.Contact.Alias);
                Console.WriteLine("Type : " + nc.Mailbox.MailboxType);
            }
        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: thank you! i ended up using LDAP. does this imply that any users added to ms excahnge are automatically also added to AD?

Comment: Yes but its the opposite to way your thinking way eg you need to create a AD Account first and then that account is Mail Enabled (this is the same for Mail Enabled Contacts, Distribution Groups, Mail Enabled Public Folders). Active Directory is Exchange's Directory Service.

Comment: aha. thanks. we arent running the excahnge server, so as long as ldap return correct data, were ok. thanks!!